# While loop only running through once... (Java)

Tags: java, loops

I just can't figure out why this loop is only running through once but it is driving me crazy. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class Test
{

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    gladiator fighterA = new gladiator("Maximus", 25, 5, 10, 11, 8, 2, 1, true);
    gladiator fighterB = new gladiator("Minimus", 22, 8, 12, 10, 8, 4, 1, true);

    while(fighterA.getAlive() == true && fighterB.getAlive() == true);
    {
        double userDmg = (fighterA.getAttack() - fighterB.getDefence())*fighterA.getModifier();
        double enemyDmg = (fighterB.getAttack() - fighterA.getDefence())*fighterB.getModifier();
        //System.out.println(userDmg);
        //System.out.println(enemyDmg);
        fighterA.setHp(fighterA.getHp() - enemyDmg);
        fighterB.setHp(fighterB.getHp() - userDmg);
        //System.out.println(fighterA.getHp());
        //System.out.println(fighterB.getHp());
        if(fighterA.getHp() <= 0)
        {
            fighterA.setAlive(false);
        }
        if(fighterB.getHp() <= 0)
        {
            fighterB.setAlive(false);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The fight is over!");

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It is because or `fighterA.getHp() <= 0` or `fighterB.getHp() <= 0`. Print these values or debug it.

Comment: == true is useless. That's a noob mistake I always made too ;). Also, you should make sure the first character in the names of your classes are capital.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by == true is useless. I know you have to use .= with strings, but after much googling, I can't find an equivalent with booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eclipse's debugging feature: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Mmmmmm, breakpoints.

Comment: And use some sort of general knowledge for code structures. Fir this problem we know that to break the loop, the expression in its total has to evaluate false at some point, so look at your expression.
Upon looking at that, one of the fighters must be "dead, so check points in a reverse chronological order to where that could happen.

I prefer desk-checking code before debugging, as you tend to spot the really dumb errors.

Comment: It was a syntax error. I didn't realise booleans are assumed to be true and that not == is needed.